# How to keep the last segment of the URL and 301 redirect it?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have this URL = **domain.com/art-articles/arts/biography/2375-elias-**

and I want to 301 redirect it because I recently changed my Joomla website to something like this **domain.com/articles/art-articles/bios/item/2375-elias-**

I tried something like this but didn't worked.

```
RewriteRule ^art-articles/arts/biography/(.*) /articles/art-articles/bios/item/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You probably forgot a `$` at the end of the first parameter, ie: `^art-articles/arts/biography/(.*)$`

Comment: I tried to put the $ at the end but nothing changed. I keep redirecting to domain.com/articles/art-articles/bios/item/ . The last segment is missing.

Comment: Never mind. Firefox Cache was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is this. My Firefox Cache was the problem.

```
RewriteRule ^art-articles/arts/biography/(.*)$ /articles/art-articles/bios/item/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Actually I haven't tested back my initial code. I have found many examples in the net without the $ at the end. So most probably it works both ways.